# Passing a member function of another class into a std::function parameter

Tags: c++, class, c++11, function-pointers, std-function

I have a class with a function that takes a `std::function` and stores it. This part seems to compile ok (but please point out any issue if there are any)

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct worker
{
   std::function<bool(std::string)> m_callback;
   void do_work(std::function<bool(std::string)> callback)
   {
      m_callback = std::bind(callback, std::placeholders::_1);
      callback("hello world\n");
   }
};

// pretty boring class - a cut down of my actual class
struct helper
{
   worker the_worker;
   bool work_callback(std::string str)
   {
      std::cout << str << std::endl;
      return true;
   }
};

int main()
{
   helper the_helper;
   //the_helper.the_worker.do_work(std::bind(&helper::work_callback, the_helper, std::placeholders::_1));  // <---- SEGFAULT (but works in minimal example)
   the_helper.the_worker.do_work(std::bind(&helper::work_callback, &the_helper, std::placeholders::_1));  // <---- SEEMS TO WORK
}
```

I get a *segfault*, but I am not sure why. I have used this before, in fact, I copied this example from another place I used it. The only real difference that the member function was part of the class I called it from (i.e. `this` instead of `the_helper`).

So this is why I am also asking if there is anything else I am doing wrong in general? Like should I be passing the `std::function` as:

```
void do_work(std::function<bool(std::string)>&& callback)
```

or

```
void do_work(std::function<bool(std::string)>& callback)
```

Comment: @AMA sorry - typeo - fixed

Comment: The bigger problem with hand copied code is that when all the typos are fixed, the problem doesn't reoccur http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f68ad0b1afc252f9

Comment: @StoryTeller Remove the `return false;` you have in there and enjoy that segfault :P @OP can you confirm?

Comment: you took the time to create a stripped down version of your problem. This is excelent. You did the arguably hardest part. But you need to make the [MCVE]. For just a little effort on your part you could have a snippet of code that we can copy-paste and compile. As it is your code doesn't compile and you will lose people willing to help, but not willing to do your part - which is the correct approach. Please help yourself and create a MCVE.

Comment: @code_fodder Really there's no reason to hand copy code, all that happens is that you get a different question answered than the one you intended. Cut and paste!

Comment: In std::bind `&the_helper` perhaps?

Comment: @Rakete1111 - Well, here's me raising my glass to `-pedantic-errors`

Comment: @john and other...yeah I know, but I have no choice because I am editing on a secure PC and have to email on a PC with no tools : ( I will try to make it minimal complete example...

Comment: You can first run your code on online ide (as provided links).

Comment: @StoryTeller I could not get that tool to work (my internet is also locked down), but I found another site that I could use. I did not see the segfault that I am getting in my main code... which really puzzled me. Then I noticed that `this` is a pointer and `the_helper` is not. I used `&the_helper` and then my main program (which I can't print here as its too big) started to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As also noted by @Rakete1111 in comments, the problem probably was in this code:

```
bool work_callback(std::string str)
{
   std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

In C++ if a non-void function does not return a value the result is undefined behavior.

This example will crash with [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zHDIl3OOcJBQcsHW) but pass with [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LT9PRNz3BNSb8XOv).

If `helper::work_callback` returns (e.g, `true`) the code works just [fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gKvNic6Lkc1gJz4R).

Comment: This is a valid point. But it was not the cause of my issue. My problem did not manifest in the MCVE... but by writing it it did help me find the issue `the_helper` should be `&the_helper`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your code seg faults because I was spoiled and skipped `std::bind` straight to lambdas. Since you use `C++11` you should really convert your code from `std::bind` to lambdas:

```
struct worker
{
   std::function<bool(std::string)> m_callback;

   void do_work(std::function<bool(std::string)> callback)
   {
      m_callback = callback;
      callback("hello world\n");
   }
};
```

Now with `work_callback` and calling `do_work` things need some analysis.

First version:

```
struct helper
{
   worker the_worker;
   bool work_callback(std::string)
   {
      return false;
   }
};

int main()
{
   helper the_helper;
   the_helper.the_worker.do_work([&](std::string s) { return the_helper.work_callback(s); });
}
```

Now this version works with your toy example. However out in the wild you need to be careful. The lambda passed to `do_work` and then stored in `the_worker` captures `the_helper` by reference. This means that this code is valid only if the `helper` object passed as reference to the lambda outlives the `worker` object that stores the `m_callback`. In your example the `worker` object is a sub-object of the the `helper` class so this is true. However if in your real example this is not the case or you cannot prove this, then you need to capture by value.

First attempt to capture by value (does not compile):

```
struct helper
{
   worker the_worker;
   bool work_callback(std::string)
   {
      return false;
   }
};

int main()
{
   helper the_helper;
   the_helper.the_worker.do_work([=](std::string s) { return the_helper.work_callback(s); });
}
```

This does not compile because the copy of `the_helper` stored in the lambda object is `const` by default and as such you cannot call `work_callback` on it.

A questionable solution if you can't make `work_callback` const is to make the lambda `mutable`:

```
struct helper
{
   worker the_worker;
   bool work_callback(std::string)
   {
      return false;
   }
};

int main()
{
   helper the_helper;
   the_helper.the_worker.do_work([=](std::string s) mutable { return the_helper.work_callback(s); });
}
```

But you need to think if this is what you intended.

What would make more sense is to make `work_callback` const:

```
struct helper
{
   worker the_worker;
   bool work_callback(std::string) const
   {
      return false;
   }
};

int main()
{
   helper the_helper;
   the_helper.the_worker.do_work([=](std::string s) { return the_helper.work_callback(s); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for getting `SEGFAULT` has been already mentioned in the comments.

However, I would like to point out that, you need to use **neither** `std::bind` **nor** `std::function`, here in your given case. Instead, simply having a [*lambda*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and a [*function pointer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) you can handle what you intend to do.

```
struct worker
{
    typedef bool(*fPtr)(const std::string&); // define fun ptr type 
    fPtr m_callback;
    void do_work(const std::string& str)
    {
        // define a lambda
        m_callback = [](const std::string& str)
        { 
            /* do something with string*/ 
            std::cout << "Call from worker: " << str << "\n";
            return true;
        }; 
        bool flag = m_callback(str);// just call the lambda here
        /* do some other stuff*/ 
    }
};

struct helper 
{
    worker the_worker;
    bool work_callback(const std::string& str)
    {
        std::cout << "Call from helper: ";
        this->the_worker.do_work(str);
        return true; ------------------------>// remmeber to keep the promise
    }
};
```

And use case would be:

```
int main()
{
    helper the_helper;
    the_helper.work_callback(std::string("hello world"));

    // or if you intend to use

    the_helper.the_worker.do_work(std::string("hello world"));

    return 0;
}
```

see <kbd>[**Output here**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cIW9B6PhY277tkuY)</kbd>:

---

**PS**: In the above case, if `worker` does not required `m_callback` for later cases(i.e, only for `do_work()`), then you can remove this member, as lambdas can be created and called at same place where it has been declared.

```
struct worker
{
    void do_work(const std::string& str)
    {
        bool flag = [](const std::string& str)->bool
        { 
            /* do something with string*/ 
            std::cout << "Call from worker: " << str << "\n";
            return true; 
        }(str); -------------------------------------> // function call
        /* do other stuff */
    }
};
```